# unable to setup point to point network between two openwrt boards

Tags: linux, wifi, access-point, openwrt, adhoc-network

I am trying to setup point to point networks between two Avila boards (Processor    : XScale-IXP42x Family) running Openwrt( KAMIKAZE 8.09.1) and Linux kernel 2.6.26.8.

I am trying to setup two configurations :
1. AP-Client
2. Adhoc-Adhoc

I tried both but nothing seems to work. I am able to setup the respective AP, Client and Adhoc modes but they somehow don't associate with other peer. I am using madwifi(atheros) driver.

For e.g. - one configuration :

```
 iwconfig ath0
 ath0      IEEE 802.11g  ESSID:"wsid"  Nickname:""
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
      Bit Rate:1 Mb/s   Tx-Power:28 dBm   Sensitivity=1/1  
      Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=0/70  Signal level=-97 dBm  Noise level=-97 dBm
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Same thing happens when I use the Ad-hoc mode. It gets the configuration but Access point remains Not-Associated.

I would love to share more details but Can someone provide me some leads into this. I just want to ping one board from other.

Please help me migrate this problem on relevant forum in case it does not belong here.

Thanks

Comment: Why on earth are you using Kamikaze? That's utterly ancient and unsupported anymore. Use the current release (Barrier Breaker).

Comment: not sure but will that support the the older kernels with madwifi. I plan to use ubiquiti XR7 cards further and I found that this particular configuration supports it

Answer (score 0):

Ok it worked finally. It seems like client mode definitely have some problem on older kernel but I am able to setup adhoc mode between two nodes. Only thing needs to be done is to forcibly put other machine into the cell of primary ad-hoc machine.

`iwconfig ath0 ap <Cell Id of priamry Ad-hoc System>`